# How to show a div only after the page render completely

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a php rendered menu. This menu is the first item to appear while my page is rendering. 
The problem is that menu apperas like a simple text list, like a broken page, so after the page render completly the menu appears as it should appear.

I already try tu use fadein, delay and nothing worked for me.
At my case, how I could show this menu only after the page load completly?
**I'm using prototype and jquery. How do it with no conflict?**

the structure at html is simple:

```
   <div id="menu">
      <nav id="mobile-menu" >
          <ul>
              <li>item</li>
              <li>item</li>
          </ul>
       </nav>
    </div>
```

Menu before page render:

[image]

Comment: If it was rendered by PHP it would be loaded before the browser received the request. I believe you have not explained this correctly. You mean javascript not PHP?

Comment: The menu render by PHP. It~s a magento store, but the menu is the js library mmenu

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you already know about this if you have tried fadein.

```
#menu {
  display: none;
}
```

I have had some problems with the jQuery implementation in the past and just used pure Javascript. Could you just put this at the bottom of your HTML page?

It is kind of a hack, but it depends on your use case.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "block";
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, but this script not works very well.. The text still appearing before completely render

Answer (score 1):

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
        src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js'> 
        </script>
    <style>
        #menu{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
      <nav id="mobile-menu" >
          <ul>
              <li>item</li>
              <li>item</li>
          </ul>
       </nav>
    </div>
</body>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').css("display", "block");
  })
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not working. I'm using prototype, there is some conflict? The script is not setting the CSS

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery below is where you need to display the menu. $( document ).ready is fired after html is renndered

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//change menu style to display
});
```

Comment: thanks! but here not works. How I write it with no conflict?

Comment: There must be an event where ur page content gets loaded u can display the menu at the end of that event. Otherwise simple thing is u can give some margin top for page content.

Comment: Like margin-top:50px;

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys!
I used your code with no conflict!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
   j( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
        j('.hide-menu').css("display", "block");
    });    
 </script>
```